# How to support 2 different application icons on 2 different devices of same resolution in android?

Tags: android, android-build-type, android-custom-drawable

I have a running app on the Google playstore. Now I have to support that application with different app icon and title on some vendor specific devices. Along with that I have to support Play store updates for my app too.

The options which I considered were,

1. create a seperate APK and preburn that apk along with vendor's build, but on upgrade the specific changes of app icon and title will be lost. As Playstore supports different apks based on the resolution but not based on the vendors.
2. create a second application by changing application's package name and maintain updates as a different app. But it is not allowed to do because of some other reasons.
3. Vendor can make my application specific changes in Launcher, so that it can replace the app icon before displaying it by package manager but that again create discrepancies as Launcher and Settings would display 2 different icons.

So I just wonder if there is an option available that I can create a separate APK on play store based on vendor, so that vendor specific icon can be supported as well as normal updates can also be supported. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not found any solution yet, then you can try below method.
Although it has not been verified, it should work.

You can use the Multiple apk support feature on Play store.
http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

As per this link, Google Play allows you to publish multiple APKs  when each APK uses filters to support a variation of the following device characteristics :

1) OpenGL texture compression formats

2) Screen size (and, optionally, screen density)

3) Device feature sets

4) API level

5) CPU architecture (ABI)

Of these except 3, all other characteristics will probably fail to differentiate your vendor from others.

**How 3(Device feature sets) can help ?**

**You can ask your vendor to create a custom dummy feature which will be used by the vendor specific version of your application(using uses-feature tag in manifest)**

Gradle supports build flavors to allow you to create multiple apks for same application.

Note : This solution is only theoretical and has not been verified.
Check the developers site for necessary details.

Please update if this solution works or you have come up with something else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But I have used activity-alias to support the same. As I needed a single APK so that I can provide the updates in next build versions with the single APK only.

In activity-alias I can define as many aliases as I want for a single activity in my manifest file and can enable and disable as per my needs.